# How to remove a component from a result of 'find_path' in CMake?

Tags: cmake

I am writing a `FindXXX.cmake` file.

To find the include, I use `find_path`:

```
find_path(XXX_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES header.h PATH_SUFFIXES XXX/XXX.h)
```

This will find the path of the header, thus in my code I'll have to include

```
#include <XXX.h>
```

Instead, I'd like to do:

```
#include <XXX/XXX.h>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `find_path` command you need to set option *NAMES* to what you want to use with `#include`:

```
find_path(XXX_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES XXX/header.h)
```

After that call and including `${XXX_INCLUDE_DIR}` you may use

```
#include <XXX/header.h>
```

in your code.